Can we express any integer as a sum of a range in 1,2,3,4,5,6... with arbitrary sign?
I was asked an interesting question. You start walking from $0$, and on every $i$`th step, you must move $i$ left or right. Your input is a destination $d$ integer, and you need to return the minimum steps to get to it.
There is an $O(N^2)$ solution for it on the geeksforgeeks website. But I found an O(1) solution for it, and verified it against the first 1000 values, so it seems correct.
Intuitively I understand what I did, but I can't put a nice mathematical proof to it. Can you help me with that please?
My solution is based on two observations.

if $f(t)$ = sum of $1,2,3,4...t$ is odd for some $t$ and $t+1$, then $f(2t)$ and $f(2t+1)$ is odd as well
if you found some $d$ in $x$ steps, then it will take $x$ steps to find $d-2i$ where $i$ is $-x > i > x$

Ok, so my algorithm is finding the min sum of $1,2,3,4...y$ such that it is bigger or equal to $d$. If it is equal or have the same reminder as $d$ when dividing by 2 then return $y$, other wise you need to return $y+1$ or $y+2$ depending or where $y$ is in the 2 reminder cycle.
Here is a Java O(1) version of it
int minSteps(int d) {
    int y = (int) Math.ceil((-1 + Math.sqrt(1 + 8 * d)) / 2);
    int s = y * (y + 1) / 2;

    if (s == d || s % 2 == d % 2) {
        return y;
    }

    int result;
    if(y % 2 == 0){
        result = y+1;
    }
    else {
        result = y+2;
    }

    return result;
}


I must be missing something.  To walk (for example) $~d = 40~$ steps to the right, you walk $~6~$ steps to the right, six separate times, and then walk $~4~$ steps to the right once.  So, you have taken seven steps, which is obviously optimal.  What am I misinterpreting?

I am a little bit suspect about Sqrt being $O(1)$. Is this really the case for integers?
